# How to set the widths of navbar items with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling to align my form in the navbar, I am using bootstrap and I have used a couple of ways to no avail. If anybody has a clue, please help.

[image: file screenshot]

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">

       <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
           <label class="sr-only" for="email">E-mail address</label>
           <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">  
       </div>
       <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
           <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
           <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Password">  
       </div>
       <div class="checkbox checkbox-sm">
          <label><input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Sign in</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you  mean by aligning the form? Bootstrap has built in classes such as `pull-left` and `pull-right`, which will float your whole container to the left or right. There is also text alignment helper classes. Edit: Looking at your screenshot, you should append the `pull-right` class to your checkbox container and submit button.

Comment: You need to post a minimal, working and **complete** example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS). See [mcve] and [ask].